# Returning data from a Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a function which I use to populate some fields at load, which looks like this:

```
function billingAddress(){
    var urls = ['myURL'];
    var output = [];
    Promise.all(
        urls.map(
            u=>fetch(u).then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Http Error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
        )
    ).then(texts => {
        fillAddress(texts);
        var info = getCustomerInfo(texts);
        console.log(info); //returns the data
        output.push(info);
    });
    return output;
}
```

The fillAddress function just fills in the respective fields on document load. In order to place an order, I need to gather the customer info and send a post request to the server. What I don't understand is how I can save the information from getCustomerInfo so I can process it at a later time.

For your reference,

```
function getCustomerInfo(data){
    var temp = data[0]['addresses']['shipping'];
    var info = {};
    info['address1'] = temp[0];
    info['address2'] = temp[1];
    info['city'] = temp[2];
    info['zip'] = temp[3];
    info['country'] = temp[4];
    info['state'] = temp[5];
    info['phone'] = temp[8];
    info['gst'] = temp[9];
    info['email'] = temp[10];
    info['items'] = [];
    return info;
}
```

Post function:

```
function placeOrder(){
    var info = billingAddress();
    console.log(info); //returns undefined
    $.ajax({
        url: 'placeOrder',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

placeOrder() is an onclick function, so I can't run it inside billingAddress()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your `info` data asynchronously, so you must access it asynchronously. What this means is that you can't return a value which is obtained from an asynchronous function call in a synchronous function, like you are trying to do with pushing `info` to `output` and then returning `output`. What is happening in your function is that `output` is being immediately returned as an empty array, while your asynchronous code executes in the background and then updates this array but only after it has already been returned. Instead, you should return a promise from your `billingAddress` function and access the data in the promise callback:

```
function billingAddress(){
    var urls = ['myURL'];
    return Promise.all(
        urls.map(
            u=>fetch(u).then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Http Error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
        )
    ).then(texts => {
        fillAddress(texts);
        return getCustomerInfo(texts);
    });
}

function placeOrder(){
    billingAddress().then(info => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'placeOrder',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also, I would recommend using `const` or `let` instead of `var` and `async/await` to handle your promises, which will result in cleaner code:

```
async function billingAddress(){
    try {
        const urls = ['myURL'];
        const texts = await Promise.all(
            urls.map(u => {
                const response = await fetch(u);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Http Error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
        );
        return getCustomerInfo(fillAddress(texts));
    } catch (e) {
        // handle errors
    }
}

async function placeOrder(){
    try {
        const info = await billingAddress();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'placeOrder',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        // handle errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't he just use async/await as well?

Comment: @JoelHager absolutely, but that doesn't change whether the code is asynchronous or not. Judging from the use of `var` in this code, I'm not sure what ES standard OP is using

Comment: This works just fine for me. I'm trying to wrap my head around the asynchronous nature of js. Thank you!

Comment: @megadarkfriend no problem, I also added an edit using `async/await` syntax as suggested by JoelHager

Comment: Well, the `await` part of it would technically act like synchronous logic. That's all I was getting at. :)